# Convert Invoke-RestMethod output to object

Tags: rest, powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell `Invoke-RestMethod` on a ticketing system's API and then convert the output into a PowerShell object.

As an example when I use `Invoke-RestMethod` to get the properties of a ticket I get this.

```
$object = Invoke-RestMethod '[URI here]'
$object.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


$object

EWREST_supported_user0='Yes';
EWREST_updater_team='Support Team';
EWREST_eng_id='CLT';
EWREST_testlabelsub='Test Label';
EWREST_time_created='17:21:03';
EWREST_cr_conversion_related_to='Support Case';
EWREST__1901_full_name='secuser Testuser1';
EWREST_summary='Ticket Title';
EWREST_i_would_like_to_reopen_my_ticket='No';
EWREST_assigned_team_leader='Agiloft Admin';
EWREST_id='183255';
EWREST_severity='Sev 4';
EWREST_problem_description='<div>This is an example of a ticket note that takes up multiple lines when read via API<\/div><div>&nbsp;<\/div><div>Example note info here<\/div><div>&nbsp;<\/div>
<div>Additional example note info here<\/div><div>&nbsp;<\/div><div>Even more note info here<\/div>';
EWREST_demo_data='No';
```

What I would like to be able to do is manipulate `$object` as an object by doing things like `$object.EWREST_category` and get "Networking".  So I have been trying to figure out how to maniuplate `$object` which is just a string of attributes to a traditional PowerShell object with properties.

Can someone offer some pointers on how to go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a string with key/value pairs I'd just do a little cleanup (remove the single quotes and the semicolons), convert the string to a hashtable, then build a custom object from that:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod '[URI here]'

$props  = $response -replace "'" -replace ';' | ConvertFrom-StringData
$object = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $props
```

**Edit:** To mangle the multiline value into one line you can use another replacement with a negative lookbehind assertion (`(?<!...)`) that removes newlines only if they're not preceded by a single quote followed by a semicolon. However, since that same property contains other semicolons you also need to modify the semicolon replacement, so that it only removes semicolons if they're followed by a newline or the end of the string (using a positive lookahead assertion, `(?=...)`).

```
$props  = $response -replace "(?<!';)`n" -replace "'" -replace ";(?=`n|`$)" |
          ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Comment: Thank you this looks like it will work well for me.  I do have one issue though, one of the properties is a multiline property.  And that seems to break the ConvertFrom-StringData command.  ie on the first new line it gets "Data Line  new line at line:3 char 44 is not in name=value format"  any idea how to prevent that?

Comment: That depends on what the actual data look like. Please update the example in your question.

Comment: I've updated the example in my quesiton to include the property EWREST_problem_description that is multiple lines and causes an issue with ConvertFrom-StringData command.  When it gets to the second line of this property it doesnt see it as a name=value format.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe next naive script could suffice?

```
$ob=  "EWREST_supported_user0='Yes';
EWREST_category='Networking';
EWREST_updater_team='Admin Team';
EWREST_time_created='12:56:53';
EWREST_cr_conversion_related_to='Support Case';
"                                         # this is that string

       # transform string to an array:
$oba = $ob.Split("`r`n", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

$obah=@{}                                 # create empty hash table
                                          # and fill it from array then:
$oba | ForEach-Object { 
        $aux=$_.split('=;')               #       key / value pair
        $obah[$aux[0]] = $aux[1] }        # hash[key] = value

$obah.Keys                   # display hash table keys (only debug)
$obah.EWREST_time_created    # hash table item use (example: property)
$obah['EWREST_category']     # hash table item use (another approach: index)
```